# Query where based on the values of a field that is an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, rails-activerecord

I have a class `User` that has a field `permissions` that is an array.

```
t.text  "permissions",  default: [],  array: true
```

The array `permissions` could have one or more of the strings `admin`, `guest`, and `editor`.

How do I write a `where` query to retrieve all `Users` which have a specific permission, say `editor`? I want to do this in my controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you're using PostgreSQL, you use [`any`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparisons.html#AEN21103):

> **9.23.3. ANY/SOME (array)**
>
> > `expression operator ANY (array expression)`
> >     `expression operator SOME (array expression)`
>
> The right-hand side is a parenthesized expression, which must yield an array value. The left-hand expression is evaluated and compared to each element of the array using the given `operator`, which must yield a Boolean result.

Using `x = any(some_array)` is a convenient way of checking if `x` is equal to any of the elements of `some_array` so you could say:

```
User.where(':permission = any(permissions)', :permission => your_permission)
```

You could also use the [overlaps operator (`&&`)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html#ARRAY-OPERATORS-TABLE)

```
User.where('permissions && array[?]', your_permission)
```

The `array[...]` syntax is a convenient way to build array literals in PostgreSQL without having to worry about quoting issues too much.

Answer (score -3):

If you are using SQL database:

```
User.where('permissions like ?', "%editor%")
```

Comment: I want to do this in my controller.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the answer because it had a mistake.